# Custom URL without "cannot open" error

Tags: javascript, ios, url, redirect

I've implemented custom URLs in my app, and they work fine.  I've also implemented custom landing pages that show different videos based on a query parameter.

1) I would like to generate links for Twitter, email, etc. that launch my app if the user clicks on a link on a mobile phone.  If the user does not have the app installed, it should go to the landing page in the mobile browser. The link should go to the landing page if clicked on major desktop browsers.

2) On the landing page, I would like to have a link to open up the app.  If the app isn't installed, the link should open the app store listing.

On StackExchange and Google, I've found these proposed solutions:

A) http://mobify.me/static/tests/test-app-link.html

B) http://aawaara.com/post/74543339755/smallest-piece-of-code-thats-going-to-change-the

These solutions are for part 2) above. However, even the canonical version like A) still generates a "cannot open" error in Mobile Safari before redirecting.

Can anyone tell how to write a redirect service for 1) above?

I'd also love a pointer to a good example of how to handle 2) without a error alert box.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Hmmn.  I guess I want (a) above to work without the pesky alert box error popping up.  Is that better?

I am surprised that no one has ever posted a solution to 1) above.  A lot of apps have to deal with custom URLs, and the behavior I describe is desirable in a broad range of use cases.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you break this into two questions, and if possible include some of what you've already done.

Answer (score 0):

You question is fairly long but I am pretty sure this link is what you are looking for: http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/25539969-How-to-Deeplink-to-Your-Mobile-App-from-Your-Website

We used the concepts to create something similar to what you are looking to do.

Comment: Thanks!  That is close, but it still pops us the pesky error alert box before redirecting in mobile safari.  Can you see that too? http://getsilly.co/static/test.html

Also, it open ups the app store (instead of redirecting) if you open it up in safari on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

OK, my friend and former CTO gave me an awesome pointer.  You can use a iframe to check, which is a solid technique.  He has an example, which I can confirm works well on mobile safari.

Here is the code and example on github:
https://github.com/hampusohlsson/browser-deeplink

Hope that helps!